# Drag and drop in Swing is disabled when JxBrowser HEAVYWEIGHT is used

Tags: java, linux, swing, jtabbedpane, jxbrowser

I'm trying to get Drag and Drop to work with JxBrowser in Linux. I want in one tab to be able to drag and drop in my swing components and in another tab to have jxbrowser. However, when adding jxbrowser to another tab drag and drop stops working.

This code reproduces the problem when trying to drag the label in the "Text" tab`:

```
public class TabbedPaneSample {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = new Browser(BrowserType.HEAVYWEIGHT);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label Text");
        label.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
                JComponent comp = (JComponent) evt.getSource();
                TransferHandler th = comp.getTransferHandler();
                th.exportAsDrag(comp, evt, TransferHandler.COPY);
            }
        });

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Browser", new BrowserView(browser));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Text", label);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        browser.loadURL("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Changing `BrowserType.HEAVYWEIGHT` to `BrowserType.LIGHTWEIGHT` makes it work.

Can I somehow work around this problem?

Comment: Swing works usually with lightweigth components, and some features of this framework are not applicable for heavy-weight components. In this case you should use low-level AWT support (if exists). In your case you should try to use classes from `java.awt.dnd` to provide D-n-D support for your components.

Comment: I know, it works on Windows and Mac and since I'm not mixing the components (rendering light components over heavy components) and given that the example comes from [jxbrowser docs](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013728-jtabbedpane) themselves I would argue that it could be possible. JxBrowser is really slow in `LIGHTWEIGHT` mode.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the moment, Drag & Drop does not work on Linux in a heavyweight mode in JxBrowser. We already have an opened task regarding this and will implement this functionality in one of the future JxBrowser versions.

For now, as a workaround, I can suggest you try a lightweight mode as Drag & Drop should be working in this mode on Linux.

As for the lightweight mode being slower than a heavyweight mode, perhaps you can try an accelerated lightweight mode which is about ~30% faster: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000104965-accelerated-lightweight-rendering